# Spring Default Profile Selection Based on Scope

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My application has an embedded database as a "test" dependency (Maven test), but this causes an exception when you want to start the application without any -D switches because the jdbc driver is declared in the application.yml (see below).

Is it possible to set the datasource based on the scope (i.e. runtime or test)? Or better yet can you change the default profile without any -D switches (e.g. -Dspring.profiles.active=test)?

This might seem trivial, but it's confusing for our team that you can successfully run tests in your IDE, but then when you try to "run the application" it fails unless you set the -D switch.

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:h2

spring:
  profiles: profile1

datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the embedded database only for tests, then you can place an application.properties (or .yml) in the folder `src/test/resources/` where you put all properties for test running in. At least that works for me. So you don't need to put your production properties into a profile and they are used when you run your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `application.yml` in `src/test/resources/`
2. You can set the default profile with

```
    datasource.url=jdbc:h2  =>

    datasource:
      url: jdbc:h2  
    ---

    spring:
      profiles: profile1

    datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql
```

Comment: I need to set the default profile based on whether I'm running tests or not so that unfortunately that doesn't work. Do you know a way to set the profile based on whether I'm running tests or normally?